# Modify a ListView Item

Tags: android, listview, textview

I declared my array adapter with a `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` and the checkboxes show up in the list as they should, but it seems that when a new item is added the background color  does not shift down with the new items and is applied to the new item.

```
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, todoItems);
    myListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    myListView.setChoiceMode(myListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

...

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(myListView.isItemChecked(i)){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You checked " + todoItems.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You unchecked " + todoItems.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried to change the background color with `view` and `myListView`, but neither worked. It seems like the items aren't linking with the background color...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have this attribute to your ListView in XML

android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

Answer (score 0):

When i wanted to modify the look of my listview, I had to manually go into the xml file for `simple_list_item_one` (`simple_list_item_multiple_choice` in your case). I made a copy of that file with a different name. I modified that duplicate to make the listview look how I wanted. Its basically a rectangular relative layout so it's really not that hard to work your way through it.